# sprintf, printf and format specifiers

Tags: c, printf

I'm having trouble understanding what this line of code does:

```
    sprintf(obj, "%s.o", root);
```

obj and root are both character buffers, from what I read root is basically copied to obj?
I'm not sure what "%s.o" is doing. %s is to specify a String but the .o?

thanks for any help

Comment: Is it just adding .o to the end of the root and moving the whole thing to obj?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%s` will be replaced with the contents of `root`, and followed by the `.o` part of the string, which is just an "additional" text. For example, if `root` has "file", `obj` will be set to "file.o".

Comment: Strictly, only the contents up to (but not including) the first 0 byte will be copied.

Comment: Maybe that's too strictly… :-) but thanks for pointing it out